# Counting hours from closed circuit

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, timer

A complete ignorant here.

I am trying to custom-build some sort of lab timer with an external trigger (the longest-running one that I found to buy was up to 24 hr and I need one that is up to 72 hr).

The problem is I really would not know where to start (I've been thinking of using a Raspberry Pi for this, because I am computer-savvy, but it does seem like overkill).

I would appreciate it if someone can give me some pointers about where to start.

The objective is as follows:

I need to measure how much time, in hours, has elapsed from the moment water was spilled in my lab system. It seemed like a straightforward thing - as soon as two conductors get wet, a circuit gets closed and a timer starts. I just need the "timer" part so I can register the hours from the point of failure (in case it had happened during the night, or the weekend).

An Arduino-based timer would be good if there is an easy way for me to register time, without having to buy a display (ending with spending almost as much money as I would for a Raspberry Pi Zero with less added value).

Comment: Simple hours meter as used on trucks and tractors - supply 12V and it runs so all you need to do is switch a supply.

Comment: if you know how to program an arduino: what's stopping you? You could just let that thing continously output the time your contacts were shorted over the UART every 5 seconds (or so). On arriving at the scene, you connect your laptop / the device with a display you have at hand, via a USB-serial converter and read the time. More sense would probably make having the thing keep time (I bet there's arduinos whose microcontroller has a built-in real-time clock) and a log that records events (like: got wet at time x, got dry at time y, temperature over 100° at z) and outputs said log on request)

Comment: How do you expect to know how much time has elapsed "without having to buy a display"? How much resolution do you need for the duration...minutes? seconds? How much accuracy do you need...+/- 1 second? +/- 1 minute?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just need to know when the spill happened?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I can do with an +/- 0.5 hr.

Comment: @SolarMike Good one. this might do the trick. One question though: is this not induction based? should there not be a device connected to the circute?

Comment: @MarcusMüller That too is a good idea, however I lack the approch to the circut with a computer, thus I have to have something a little simpler... Thanks.

Comment: @stretch I do need to know when the spill happened. I need to know with an half hour resolution, **within 72 hr**. That's the main problem.

Comment: Available as dugital or analogue (ie rotating wheels), choose what you want. Check how they work and then you will know how to connect them.

Comment: What I meant was elapsed time until what happens. If someone walks into the lab and notices his feet are wet and turns off the water there should be a sign near the shutoff asking him to write down the date/time. I don't understand your problem,

Comment: @stretch There are two problems with your idea: 1. there is a finite and rather small amount of water (not enough to get on someone's shoes, not that I would want such a thing to happen). 2. I will still not be able to know **when** this happened, in case it happens during the night or the weekend.